# Can I call the Graph API within Azure functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am new to azure functions.
I created a ReactApp and used the graph API to get information about users registered in Azure ADB2C.
At this time, a client credential flow was used, but user information could not be obtained due to a CORS error.

> Previous Idea(CORS error): ReactApp↔graphAPI↔Azure ADB2C

So I thought of using Azure functions.
First, ReactApp calls azure functions as an API.
Next, call the graphAPI in the azure functions.
At this point, we want to use the client credential flow.
Then, the user data of Azure ADB2C can be obtained because the graphAPI was used.
This user data is returned to Azure functions so that it can be used in ReactApp.

> My Idea: ReactApp↔Azure functions ↔ graph API ↔　Azure ADB2C

Is this feasible?
If it is possible and you have a sample, please let me know.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Yes it's possible, could you share which `Graph API` endpoint you would like to call??

Comment: thank you for comment!
I want to get username...so I think this is it.
I want to call graphAPI based on the userId contained in the ID token.
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/identities`

Comment: How are you getting the `Id Token` within the function can you please share?

Comment: Hi @juckier, if the provided answer resolved your issue, you may mark it as answer or upvote it so that others who encounter the similar issue, it may be useful for them or community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   Yes, you can surely do the same as per what you have stated in your post.  You can surely **deploy a react app in Azure functions and trigger a graph API query from the function to an Azure AD B2C tenant**. To do so, you will have to first **deploy an Azure Static Web app in Azure, then build and deploy it through a workflow in Github by creating a repository there, then create an Azure function API for the react app deployed**. This `Azure function service provides serverless APIs which allows you to focus on your TypeScript code and not have to configure a full back-end web server`.

•   Once done, then **connect the react client app to Azure function API**. The `Azure static web app resource deployed earlier provides a proxy between the react client and the Azure function API`. Hence, while deploying the above, I would suggest you to please follow the below Microsoft documentation link and its subsequent article series for the said above resources.

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/how-to/with-web-app/static-web-app-with-swa-cli/introduction**

Please follow the series of documentation articles stated above till the end of connecting the react client to Azure function API. Once done, then `register an application in Azure AD B2C for authentication purposes and copy the application’s required credentials like the client ID, tenant ID, tenant name and client secret for inserting these details in the HTTP trigger function API created earlier. Also, give the registered application in Azure AD B2C the required application permissions of ‘User.ReadWrite.All’ for the Microsoft Graph API. Ensure that you are adding the ‘Microsoft.Identity.Client’, ‘Microsoft.Graph.Auth’ and ‘Microsoft.Graph.Beta’ nuget packages` to your Azure function solution created earlier. Then **modify the constant parameters and variables in the Azure solution code file** as in the below snapshot: -

[image: Azure function code]

•   Once the above has been done successfully, you can then test the **deployed solution through ‘Postman’ application API as well as by redirecting to the react app page there by triggering a HTTP response in the function API which will ensure that you read the logged in Azure AD B2C user in the react app**. For detailed information on the above-mentioned configuration, I would suggest you to please go through the video link below as it perfectly describes your condition in detail: -

[image: Azure function to Azure AD B2C]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4uJHSwA-TZE